# Faster way to count number of timestamps before another timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I have two dataframe "train" and "log". "log" has datetime columns "time1" while train has datetime column "time2". For every row in "train" I want to find out counts of "time1" when "time1" is before "time2".

I already tried the apply method with dataframe.

```py
def log_count(row):
    return sum((log['user_id'] == row['user_id']) & (log['time1'] < row['time2']))
train.apply(log_count, axis = 1)
```

It is taking very long with this approach.

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566368/inequality-joins-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do this once for each (paired) `user_id` group, you could do the following:

- Create a column called `is_log` which is `1` in `log` and `0` in `train`:

  ```
  log['is_log'] = 1
  train['is_log'] = 0
  ```

  The `is_log` column will be used to keep track of whether or not a row comes from `log` or `train`.
- Concatenate the `log` and `train` DataFrames:

  ```
  combined = pd.concat(
      [log.rename(columns=dict(time1="time")), train.rename(columns=dict(time2="time"))],
      axis=0,
      ignore_index=True,
      sort=False,
  )
  ```
- Sort the `combined` DataFrame by `user_id` and `time`:

  ```
  combined = combined.sort_values(by=["user_id", "time"])
  ```

  So now `combined` looks something like this:

  ```
           time  user_id  is_log
  6  2000-01-17        0       0
  0  2000-03-13        0       1
  1  2000-06-08        0       1
  7  2000-06-25        0       0
  4  2000-07-09        0       1
  8  2000-07-18        0       0
  10 2000-03-13        1       0
  5  2000-04-16        1       0
  3  2000-08-04        1       1
  9  2000-08-17        1       0
  2  2000-10-20        1       1
  ```
- Now the count that you are looking for can be expressed as a cumulative sum of the `is_log` column, grouped by `user_id`:

  ```
  combined["count"] = combined.groupby("user_id")["is_log"].cumsum()
  train = combined.loc[combined["is_log"] == 0]
  ```

  This is the main idea: Counting the number of `1`s in the `is_log` column is equivalent to counting the number of times in `log` which come before each time in `train`.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2019)


def random_dates(N):
    return np.datetime64("2000-01-01") + np.random.randint(
        365, size=N
    ) * np.timedelta64(1, "D")


N = 5
log = pd.DataFrame({"time1": random_dates(N), "user_id": np.random.randint(2, size=N)})
train = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time2": np.r_[random_dates(N), log.loc[0, "time1"]],
        "user_id": np.random.randint(2, size=N + 1),
    }
)

log["is_log"] = 1
train["is_log"] = 0
combined = pd.concat(
    [log.rename(columns=dict(time1="time")), train.rename(columns=dict(time2="time"))],
    axis=0,
    ignore_index=True,
    sort=False,
)
combined = combined.sort_values(by=["user_id", "time"])
combined["count"] = combined.groupby("user_id")["is_log"].cumsum()
train = combined.loc[combined["is_log"] == 0]

print(log)
#        time1  user_id  is_log
# 0 2000-03-13        0       1
# 1 2000-06-08        0       1
# 2 2000-10-20        1       1
# 3 2000-08-04        1       1
# 4 2000-07-09        0       1

print(train)
```

yields

```
         time  user_id  is_log  count
6  2000-01-17        0       0      0
7  2000-06-25        0       0      2
8  2000-07-18        0       0      3
10 2000-03-13        1       0      0
5  2000-04-16        1       0      0
9  2000-08-17        1       0      1
```