# Pandas merge on inequality

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, join

So I have been searching a pandas equivalent of this SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.columnX>=table2.columnY
```

**Note that I am joining by an inequality condition, `>=`, not by matching columns.*

But it seems panda's merge is only able to join by exact matches (like `select * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.columnX=table2.columnY`)

It doesn't seems it supports joining by more complex conditions, like a column having a value greater than the other column. Which SQL does support

I have found many resources that say it does not supports that, and that the only way to do so is to do a cartersian product first and then filter the resulting dataframe. Or pre-filtering the dataframes before joining. However, a cartesian product is costly

But those sources I have found are from more than 5 years ago. Is it still the same case today that panda's merge can only join by matching columns exactly and it does not admit inequalities (<,>,<=,>=,between)?

Here are some old resources I have found regarding this:

[Inequality joins in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566368/inequality-joins-in-pandas)

[Merge pandas dataframes where one value is between two others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others)

[Best way to join / merge by range in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas/44601120#44601120)

Comment: Have a look at [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) which covers inequality joins and avoids cartesian joins

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, the **merge** function is primarily intended for combining based on exact matches between columns.

**You can use this code as an example :**

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data1 = {'columnX': [10, 15, 20]}
data2 = {'columnY': [5, 12, 18]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Perform a cartesian product
cartesian = pd.merge(df1.assign(key=1), df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)

# Filter based on inequality condition
result_df = cartesian[cartesian['columnX'] >= cartesian['columnY']]

print(result_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) covers inequality joins efficiently (under the hood it uses binary search)

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
from janitor import col
``
# code adapted from
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601120/7175713
table1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        columnX=range(5),
        value=range(5, 105, 21)
     ))
table2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        columnY=range(3),
        low=[0, 30, 30],
        high=[10, 40, 50]
   ))

table1
   columnX  value
0        0      5
1        1     26
2        2     47
3        3     68
4        4     89

table2
   columnY  low  high
0        0    0    10
1        1   30    40
2        2   30    50

table1.conditional_join(table2, col('columnX') >= col('columnY'))
    columnX  value  columnY  low  high
0         0      5        0    0    10
1         1     26        0    0    10
2         1     26        1   30    40
3         2     47        0    0    10
4         2     47        1   30    40
5         2     47        2   30    50
6         3     68        0    0    10
7         3     68        1   30    40
8         3     68        2   30    50
9         4     89        0    0    10
10        4     89        1   30    40
11        4     89        2   30    50


table1.conditional_join(table2, ('columnX','columnY','>='))
    columnX  value  columnY  low  high
0         0      5        0    0    10
1         1     26        0    0    10
2         1     26        1   30    40
3         2     47        0    0    10
4         2     47        1   30    40
5         2     47        2   30    50
6         3     68        0    0    10
7         3     68        1   30    40
8         3     68        2   30    50
9         4     89        0    0    10
10        4     89        1   30    40
11        4     89        2   30    50
```

Range joins are also implemented efficiently, and you can get speedups if you have numba installed:

```py
table1.conditional_join(table2, col('value') > col('low'), col('value') < col('high'))
   columnX  value  columnY  low  high
0        0      5        0    0    10
1        2     47        2   30    50

table1.conditional_join(table2, ('value','low','>'), ('value', 'high', '<'))
   columnX  value  columnY  low  high
0        0      5        0    0    10
1        2     47        2   30    50
```

If you are looking for just the first match, where columnX >= columnY, then `pd.merge_asof` covers you nicely and efficiently as well:

```py
pd.merge_asof(table1, table2, left_on = 'columnX', right_on='columnY')
   columnX  value  columnY  low  high
0        0      5        0    0    10
1        1     26        1   30    40
2        2     47        2   30    50
3        3     68        2   30    50
4        4     89        2   30    50
```

Note that for `pd.merge_asof`, your join columns should be sorted; [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) takes care of that under the hood.