Join two Pandas Dataframes based on multiple conditions
I have below Dataframes
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['AA', 'AA'], 'col2' : [10,20]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['AA', 'BB', 'AA', 'BB'], 'col2' : [11,11,11,11]})

Now I want to left-join above 2 based on col1 and col2 where dat1.col2  < dat2.col2
I tried below:
dat_com = pd.merge(dat1, dat2, how = 'left', on = 'col1')
dat_com[dat_com['col2_x'] < dat_com['col2_y']]

But I think this is wrong approach as it eliminates the second row of dat1, which I think should be in the final dat_com as I am left-joining.
Could you please help to correct above method?

Why do you think it should include second row? Your second condition about col2_x being less than col2_y eliminates this row from the final result

Because it is left-join. Therefore there should be last row with dat_com .col2_x = 20 and dat_com .col2_y = NaN

That row would be there if there were no matches. But there are matches in the right side, so the NaN row isn't added. Besides, you have a second condition that operates after the join is performed.

In other words, if your intention was to do a left join and then apply a filter to it, your code does it correctly. So maybe you actually wanted to do something else?

I want to apply these 2 condition simultaneously like SQL does

I see. Merge in pandas isn't powerful enough to do that, it can only merge on matches. But people have written custom packages. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146492/pandas-merge-on-inequality

Code
dat_com['col2_y'] = dat_com['col2_y'].where(dat_com['col2_x'] < dat_com['col2_y'])
cond1 = dat_com['col2_y'].isna()
cond2 = cond1.groupby(dat_com['index']).transform(all)
cond3 = ~cond2 & ~cond1
cond4 = cond2 & ~dat_com['index'].duplicated()
out = dat_com[cond3 | cond4]

out:
   index col1  col2_x  col2_y
0      0   AA      10    11.0
1      0   AA      10    11.0
2      1   AA      20     NaN

If you don't need the index column, delete it.

check with other example
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['AA', 'AA'], 'col2' : [10,20]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'AA', 'BB'], 'col2' : [8, 11, 12, 13, 14]})

dat1:
  col1  col2
0   AA    10
1   AA    20

dat2:
  col1  col2
0   AA     8
1   AA    11
2   BB    12
3   AA    13
4   BB    14

out:
   index col1  col2_x  col2_y
1      0   AA      10    11.0
2      0   AA      10    13.0
3      1   AA      20     NaN

